# MySQL: How to get the modularity of views, but the optimization of longer code?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, query-optimization, modularity

In both MySQL and sqlite3, **1)** writing queries with nested views is frequently much slower than just copying the code from the view and pasting it into the larger query (source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021319/how-to-optimize-mysql-views), [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/339242-sqlite-performance-problem-with-views/), [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/), personal experience).  However, **2)** I like how views make SQL code shorter and more modular, in the same way that functions make code shorter more modular in other languages.  Finally, **3)** I am  lazy, and I want the optimizer to do all the work of planning joins, picking indices, and finding efficiencies for me.  I suspect that if I wanted to get my hands dirty and plan the joins myself, I could write queries that are both modular and fast, but I don't want to do that.

Therefore, of **1)** speed, **2)** modularity, and **3)** ease, it seems that I can have only two.  **How can I have all three?**

Comment: MySQL 5.7 does a "better" job of optimizing `VIEWs`.  What version are you using?

Comment: Please note that pasting a view into a query would result in a *subquery*; your SQLite example uses two entirely different queries. SQLite [documents in excruciating details](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#flattening) under what circumstances a subquery/view cannot be optimized away.

Comment: @RickJames : I'm using 5.7.  I also notice that one of my sources ([this guy](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/)) published in 2007, not long after VIEWS were first made part of MySQL in 5.0, and before 5.1 was released.  So what you say is very plausible.

Comment: @CL : the distinction between a query with a subquery and two different queries escaped me until you pointed it out, so thank you.  I suppose I need to read the documentation you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, ordinarily the query planner handles a query constructed from views and one constructed from nested subqueries the same way.   MySQL, unlike some other makes and models of RDMS, doesn't have built-in materialized views.

But, if you want guarantees of all three of speed, modularity, and ease, you're going to have to switch to another RDMS. Oracle will do some of what you want, but to get it working you'll have to hire a DBA and pay big licensing fees.

Common Table Expressions are another way to modularize your code. [PostgreSQL handles those](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html); so do the commercial RDMSs.

Comment: Thank's to CL's point, I realize that part of my question was based on a misunderstanding of what a nested subquery was, but my search for speed, modularity, ease, and miserliness all together continues.  Maybe it's time for me to sacrifice some ease and learn about PostgreSQL, or at least read more of the documentation for MySQL.